# Can't install python packages on my ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: python, ubuntu

This is the full script:

```
(venv) ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ pip install wxPython
Collecting wxPython
  Using cached wxPython-4.2.0.tar.gz (71.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-jlwwpkvj/wxpython_66c7996a596740a4b92c4f3a3724336d/setup.py", line 27, in <module>
          from buildtools.config import Config, msg, opj, runcmd, canGetSOName, getSOName
        File "/tmp/pip-install-jlwwpkvj/wxpython_66c7996a596740a4b92c4f3a3724336d/buildtools/config.py", line 30, in <module>
          from attrdict import AttrDict
        File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/attrdict/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
          from attrdict.mapping import AttrMap
        File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/attrdict/mapping.py", line 4, in <module>
          from collections import Mapping
      ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
(venv) ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

I think cause of the problem is virtuel machine. I can download packages on my host OS.
I am using UTM for ubuntu.

I try updating pip and setuptolls. I reinstalled differently ubuntu for multiple times.
I am searcing forums for weeks and still nothing.

Comment: try it with lower version of python.

Comment: I get the same error on python3.11, so probably this module is not ready for newer python yet: https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/2296

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an older version of Python (I am guessing 3.9). The best option is probably to set it up in [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html) like this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.9
sudo apt-get install python3.9-dev python3.9-venv
python3.9 -m venv myenv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install wxPython
```

Comment: didint work. then I tried with 3.8 also didint work.

Comment: and the error is same?

Comment: yes, same error

Comment: what output do you get after running "python --version" inside created virtual environment?

Comment: 'Python 3.10.6'

Comment: when I first try 'python --version' output was 'python 3.8.15'. After closing pycharm 'python --version' didint work but when I use 'python3 --version' output was 'Python 3.10.6'

Comment: you need to run it in the virtualenv, if you are using pycharm you are probably need to set up a Run configuration.

Could you try the commands above in the terminal? not in the pycharm

Comment: I did try in the terminal. Same error.

Comment: could you try like this? all commands above, then:
python --version && pip install wxPython

what version will it show?

Comment: 'Python 3.10.6'

Comment: I think you don't have properly configure virtual environment. After installing python3.9 and activating virtualenv - why would you get 3.10?

Comment: Can i remove Python3.10? Do you think that will help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the wheel (*.whl) file for that package and then:

```
pip install <wheel file path>
```

Comment: pip install -U \
    -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 \
    wxPython  ----  is this how I suppose to download wheel file.? if so gave the same error